# How to get current login user information in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

After authenticate a user through LDAP, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/src/Simple.java, I need to retrieve the DN of the user. I tried this but it returned an empty string.

```
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
ctx.getNameInNamespace();
```

I can use the search function to find the user. However, this doesn't seem a good way because a) it is slow, b) it may have duplicate username in another OU.

```
ctx.search("DC=example,DC=org", "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=abc))", null);
```

I'm not able to find any example of that. Anyone can help?

Comment: In the example you provided, the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL you provide ***is*** the DN of the user, by definition. DIGEST-MD5 has nothing to do with it. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'current user' in an LDAP application. LDAP is used to authenticate a user by an LDAP 'bind' operation, but then the application disconnects from LDAP, after which there isn't a current user. You have to remember what user you used to do the bind.

Answer (score 0):

> After authenticate a user through LDAP, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/src/Simple.java, I need to retrieve the DN of the user.

If I understand your right, the user DN do you want is the same like your authenticated user?

This user DN is used as `Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` in example: `cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial`

Comment: It's not necessary true. If use DIGEST-MD5, the principal is going to be the user id, e.g. abc.

Comment: The questions doesn't say about DIGEST-MD5. Do you have all information about the user to create the user DN? Otherwise you have to search.

Comment: No, I don't. User only provides id and password. The only problem is the LDAP may returns more than one record if it has duplicate user id.

Answer (score 0):

We put up an example "[BasicAdminSearchBind.java](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f9a3f13fc375f6d17370b6da91adf/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicAdminSearchBind.java?at=master)" where we perform a search as a user with privileges that can see all the other entries. This will return all users which match the provided filter.

You can use

```
sr.getNameInNamespace()
```

to get the Distinguished name of the search result entry returned.